# How can quickly tell what parts of a CSS file are being used on a page?

Tags: css

I have a massive CSS file that is applied to several pages.  I'm hoping to break it down to a common CSS file and several page-level CSS files, since it is becoming difficult to work with.   Unfortunately, it's not easy to tell what exactly is common.  I was hoping there was a way to quickly see what lines/selectors were being used on a given page.  Does anyone know of a tool that can do this?  I don't want to use developer tools and go through the DOM elements one by one.  I'd like to look at the CSS file and see unused selectors grayed out or something.  Thanks!

Comment: Nice question but could you allow some freedom for any Programming language? with just using CSS and HTML it would be tough

Comment: Unfortunately, the file is an old-school CSS file.  I'm converting it to a SCSS file, though.  Does that help?  Also, the HTML is created using Freemarker Templates.

Comment: You are looking at refactoring a CSS file, which is probably manual labor intensive.  Such as tool would be bonus...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use, at least in Chrome, the **Audits** tab in the developer tools. Once you run it, it says you which styles aren't used in the current page.

Testing it on this site:
[image]

Comment: That is awesome.  I didn't know about this feature of the Chrome dev tools.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

And for Firefox there an add-on called [CSS Usage](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/css-usage/) – might be worth a look too.